# How to allow designer to edit master page in ASP.NET Web Application Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Currently the webmaster can go into IIS and edit files by using Dreamweaver.  The problem came when developers deployed a Web Application Project and the webmaster changed the master page to update the design, but then when developers deployed updates to the WAP it overwrote the master page back to the way it was.

So my question is, what is the best way to let the webmaster/designer edit the master page design in an ASP.NET WAP and keep project files in sync with developer projects?

Comment: Make the webmaster/designer edit the same file in source control that the developers are using rather than letting him/her edit the deployed version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently the webmaster can go into IIS and edit files by using
>   Dreamweaver

That means webmaster is actually editing the production copy of files. Don't do that. Why would you allow production copy to be modified. Rather, as already suggested by @BenRobinson; have webmaster make changes to the version already present in TFS (considering the face that, production branch is different in TFS than main code branching).

That way, once it's been approved that the modified changes are per requirement then you can copy the changes to production branch and do a full deployment along with other code changes.

Comment: Will suggest this to our client.  Thanks